# How to search for records with dates in the last week in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to return all records with dates in the last week. How can this be achieved?

```
SELECT * FROM tblTransaction WHERE ProductDateOut...
```

Comment: Try various options and see what happens

Comment: also do make some research on related questions

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: Standard SQL: `where productdateout > current_date - interval '7' day`

Answer (score 0):

what database you are using? in oracle db:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTransaction 
WHERE ProductDateOut > SYSDATE-7
```